# The for-loop to get the array in the ActionListener is not working

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, actionlistener

Hello I'm trying to get an array of integers from a JTextField and then use them for Bubble Sort. THhe JButton shown here is supposed to take an array from the JTextField and put it into an integer array. I think the problem is in the for loop? How do I get the for-loop to put the integers into the array? This is a part of my code:

```
public class BubbleSort implements Runnable {
private JButton addSize, addNum, bubSort;
private JLabel lblSize, lblNum;
private JTextField tfSize, tfNum;
private JPanel content, top, mid1, mid2, bottom;
private JTextArea ta;

int size, p, i, c, num;
int[] A;
String numbers;
String[] strNum;


@Override
public void run() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    ..... 
    addSize = new JButton ("Enter");
    addSize.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            try{
                int size = Integer.parseInt(tfSize.getText());
                tfNum.requestFocus();
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f.getComponent(0), "Input is not a number");
            }
        }
    });
    final int[] A = new int[size];
    addNum = new JButton (" Add ");
    addNum.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            String numbers = tfNum.getText().trim();
            String[] strNum = numbers.split(",");
            for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                try{
                    A[i] = Integer.parseInt(strNum[i]);
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(A)); //what I used to check the for loop
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException nf) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f.getComponent(0), "No parsable integer!");
                }
            }
       });
    .....

    f.pack();
    f.setSize(500,500);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setVisible(true);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new BubbleSort());
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't look like you ever initialize 'size'.

Comment: @MitchWeaver Sorry I've edited it now so that you can see 'size' is initialized in a different ActionListener

Answer (score 0):

One solution I can come up with is to use static model, so that you can modify the model in your listener instance and also allow other objects to use it. I found one [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073039/using-actionlistener-to-update-variables-in-other-classes) that similar to mine.